# Calculate the average of grades in a file. it should return None if file doesn't exist and 0.0 if it doesn't contain any grades

Tags: python, file

**input(this is what the file mygrades.txt contains)**

CS1:5.75
#
CS 2: 5.5
Mathematik 1:5.75
@!
Econ 1: 5.5
Physics:6
Chemistry:5.75
!#
@

**output : 5.70**

Code:

```py
import os

def get_average_grade(path):

    grades = []

    filesize = os.path.getsize("C:\\Users\Documents\mygrades.txt")
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None          
    with open("C:\\Users\Documents\mygrades.txt", "r") as f:
        filesize = os.path.getsize("C:\\Users\Documents\mygrades.txt")
        if filesize == 0: # not entirely correct because it might contain "#@$%$^&^&*^" for example which means no grade but wont return 0.0
            return 0.0  
        else:
            for line in f.readlines():
                if ":" in line:
                    searchforcolon = line.find(":")
                    number1 = float(line[searchforcolon + 1:])
                    grades.append(number1)
                    average = sum(grades)/len(grades)
        return average
print(get_average_grade("C:\\Users\Documents\mygrades.txt"))
```

Comment: what is the question? and provide a [mre] and what is the difference between empty and not containing grades?

Comment: Did you forget to try solving this and research your issues before asking?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `for line in f` instead of `for line in f.readlines()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want something like this:

```py
import os


def get_average_grade(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None
    grades = []
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            if ':' in line:
                _, grade = line.strip().split(':')
                if ''.join(grade.strip().split('.', maxsplit=1)).isnumeric():
                    grades.append(float(grade))
    return (grades and round(sum(grades) / len(grades), 2)) or 0.0


print(get_average_grade('myfile.txt'))
```

First of you weren't using the `path` argument properly in your function, you had to put it everywhere you used the path.

This function works pretty simply, first check if the path exists and if it doesn't return None. Then define a list and open the file (use `for line in f` instead of `for line if f.readlines()`). Then check if semicolon is in the line and split by that semicolon instead of trying to find its index, that will return a list that will contain text before and after each semicolon in that line. So extract the grade by using unpacking, then check if it can be converted to float and if that is not possible simply continue (you may want to somehow alert the user if couldn't convert to a float though). Then there is a simple short-circuiting which first checks if grades list is empty and if it is then it return `0.0` (so no grades were found), otherwise it return the average rounded to 2 decimal places

Comment: thank you so much that helps a lot. however I think that there will still be a problem.if the input is as follows: 
CS:3
# comment

math: 4   then the expected output should be 3.5 but it returns 3 which is incorrect. any idea why?

Comment: @newbie yep, now it should work fine tho, edited answer (issue was that `.isnumeric` didn't return True because there was a space so I `.strip`ed it)

Comment: @newbie Please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following articulation of your code would do the job. I assume that you want to round the average to second lower decimal:

```
v = []
with open(PATH_TO_FILE, "r") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        if ":" in l:
            v.append(float(l.split(":")[1].strip()))

print(f'{int(100 * sum(v)/len(v))/100:.2f}' if len(v) > 0 else None)
```

Comment: use `for line in f:`, it is better in this case and why do you multiply by 100 AND then divide by 100? just do `{sum(v) / len(v):.2f}`

Comment: @Matiiss noted thanks! In the original problem, the desired output is "5.70" The untruncated result is 5.708333333333333, using `f{sum(v)/len(v):.2f}` outputs "5.71" , so does `round`